# SSMS 2012 intellisense Refresh Local Cache disabled

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms-2012

I've read all sorts of suggestions about how to get intellisense to work in SSMS 2012, and one suggestion I see everywhere is to refresh the local cache.  When I go to Edit - Intellisense, the Refresh Local Cache item is disabled.  I have a query window open and pointed to a SQL 2012 database.  What am I missing?

Comment: Are all the other commands disabled in that menu as well?

Comment: Everything else is enabled.  Just refresh cache is disabled.  Also, it looks like there's a bug in Intellisense when connected via VPN whcih is how I am always connected:

Comment: http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/805430/ssms-2012-intellisense-and-vpn-problem

Comment: This is apparently not my issue though as I connected to a local SQL 2012 database and the same issue persists.  Any ideas?

Comment: Delete your Local AppData folder from your User directory and then reboot. If it persists, I'd suggest a reinstall. Seems like some registry entry or something is installed wrong or perhaps there's a conflict with some other tool....

Comment: Deleting my AppData made intellisense work when pointed to a local 2012 DB.  It still doesn't work when pointed to a remote DB when connected via VPN which is presumably a result of the issue I pointed out above.  Since I generally work through a VPN it looks like I'm going to be stuck using a 3rd party tool until MS fixes the bug.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: No problem, very strange bug!